# Adding AdBannerView into SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, adbannerview

I am currently using SpriteKit and am trying to incorporate iAd into it. From what I have seen, it seems like the best thing to do is to put it in a subclass of UIViewController since you can't add AdBannerView to an Sk Scene. However, I can't figure out how to add the UIViewContoller class to my SKScene.

My Ads class of UIViewController contains:

```
iAdSupported = iAdTimeZoneSupported()

bannerDisplayed = false

   if iAdSupported {

        iAdView = ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.Banner)

        iAdView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 - iAdView!.frame.height, iAdView!.frame.width, iAdView!.frame.height)

        iAdView?.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(iAdView!)

}
```

The class goes through and debugs like it has added to the view but is not visible on top of the SKScene.
To call the Ads Class I call:

```
var AdsController: Ads!
AdsController = Ads()
AdsController.setupAds()
```

I have also tried the following in the SKScene:

```
var currentViewController:UIViewController=UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController!
currentViewController.presentViewController(Ads, animated: true, completion: nil)`
```

I have looked at a ton of pages on this and can't seem to find anything in swift that solves this problem.

Any help would be great, Thanks so much!

Nick

Answer (score -1):

Try use this class https://github.com/sunkanmi-akintoye/iOS-Ads-Admob-and-iAd really easy to implement. 
Add this line in ViewController :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     Ads.sharedInstance.presentingViewController = self
   ...

}
```

and this for show AdBannerView :

```
Ads.sharedInstance.showInterAd()
```